# Angular Unit Test coverage getting success one time and failing another time

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-coverage

I was doing a unit test coverage for the angular app to increase the coverage percentage in Sonar QUbe.
I've written around 200 test cases for the app.
When I run 'ng test --single-run --cc'. It is getting success for all test cases one time and some test cases are failing with the error 'Uncaught Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges thrown'

**Test Case:**

```
  it('applyFilter() should emit  toolbarStateChange', () => {
    component.initialToolbarState = {
      favouriteFlag: false,
      sort: {
        key: 'TYP',
        dateSortType: 'OPENED.DESC',
        primarySort: 'TITLE',
        sortOrder: 'DESC'
      },
      search: [''],
      filterItems: [''],
      ownedbyFilter: 'test',
      event: 'SORT',
    }
    spyOn(component.toolbarStateChange, 'emit');
    component.applyFilter()
    expect(component.toolbarStateChange.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**Function in the Component:**

```
 public applyFilter() {
    this.toolbarState = this.initialToolbarState;
    const selectedFilters: any = [];
    this.currentOwnedBy = (' ' + this.selectedOwnedby).slice(1);
    this.toolbarState.filterItems = this.filterItems;
    this.toolbarState.ownedbyFilter = this.selectedOwnedby;
    this.applyDisabled = true;
    this.resetDisabled = false;

    if (this.filterItems && this.filterItems.length > 0) {
      this.filterItems.forEach(item => {
        if (item.selected) {
          selectedFilters.push(item.id);
        }
      });
    }
    if (selectedFilters.length == 0 && this.OWNEDBY.ANYONE == this.selectedOwnedby) {
      this.resetDisabled = true;
    }

    this.toolbarState.event = {
      action: 'Filter',
      target: this.splitArrayElements(selectedFilters) + ((selectedFilters.length > 0) ? ', Created By ' : 'Created By ')
        + this.selectedOwnedby
    };
    this.toolbarStateChange.emit(this.toolbarState);
    this.filterApplied.emit({
      typeFilter: this.filterItems,
      ownedBy: this.selectedOwnedby
    });
    if (this.OWNEDBY.ANYONE !== this.selectedOwnedby) {
      this.filtered = true;
    }
  }
```

The test case is just to test whether the function is emitting an output event.
Am using Angular 5 here.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this issue as well on an Angular 5 project, I am not sure what the cause of it is but I think the solution was to manually call `done` as a callback to let Jasmine know we are done with the tests.

```
 // add the done callback inside of the paranthesis
 it('applyFilter() should emit  toolbarStateChange', (done: DoneFn) => {
    component.initialToolbarState = {
      favouriteFlag: false,
      sort: {
        key: 'TYP',
        dateSortType: 'OPENED.DESC',
        primarySort: 'TITLE',
        sortOrder: 'DESC'
      },
      search: [''],
      filterItems: [''],
      ownedbyFilter: 'test',
      event: 'SORT',
    }
    spyOn(component.toolbarStateChange, 'emit');
    component.applyFilter()
    expect(component.toolbarStateChange.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // call done to let Jasmine know we are done with this test
    done();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is failing intermittently.